# How to manipulate dataset by shifting columns into row

Tags: excel

I was hoping to use excel (either VBA or a Power Query) to modify my dataset and shift the columns so that they are instead displayed as rows.

(Apologies for the formatting, I am new and the tables weren't coming out as nicely as I'd hoped)

---

I am using sales data and it is currently in the following form:

(The end goal will be using it in an Access Database and linking it to a pivot table)

Category | Segment | Brand | SKU# | DataSource | 201901 | 201902 | 201903 |...

Face     | Cleanser| Axe   | 12345| $ Volume   |     $5 |    $10 |    $16 |...

Face     | Lotion  | Dove  | 54321| $ Volume   |    $14 |    $25 |    $13 |...

---

The format I would like to move it to is:

Category | Segment | Brand | SKU# | DataSource | Year  | Value

Face     | Cleanser| Axe   | 12345| $ Volume   | 201901| $5

Face     | Cleanser| Axe   | 12345| $ Volume   | 201902| $10

Face     | Cleanser| Axe   | 12345| $ Volume   | 201903| $16

Face     | Lotion  | Dove  | 54321| $ Volume   | 201901| $14

Face     | Lotion  | Dove  | 54321| $ Volume   | 201902| $25

Face     | Lotion  | Dove  | 54321| $ Volume   | 201903| $13

---

There are 4 different data sources, but they will be in the exact same format.
I am also able to break off the Category, Segment, and Brand into a lookup table if you think that would facilitate things.

I was planning to write some code in VBA and began by setting everything out that the code would need to accomplish.  I then wrote a couple lines which promptly broke, and began looking for alternative solutions (Namely a power query).  I thought the best way would be to transpose the data, but the descriptions on each product were out of line with the rest of the data. Any resources or direction on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

---

Here is what I've attempted so far:
In VBA, I essentially had the count saved to variables as:

```vb
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source")
totalRows = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
RelColumns = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count - 7 'There are 7 columns outside the data which are constant (The Cat/Segment/Brand/Sku/datasource)
```

^Past that, I was planning on nesting loops to reference the value and then copy everything over to a new sheet. My idea was something like:

```vb
For i = 2 to TotalRows 'Gets each SKU and data source within that SKU
    For j = 1 to RelColumns 'Does each value (year) that needs to be brought across
        ...
    Next
Next
```

I wasn't sure where to go next, as I couldn't find a way to copy just those cells down and get the proper value from each (There wasn't any code I made for this, just brainstorming). Rather keep running into a wall, I tried to go at the problem from another direction:

I imported the data into Excel, and formatted it into a table. Bringing it into the power query editor, I've played around with the transform tab, using the transpose function. However, the years (because they were column headers) are removed, and the description on each product moves into the top of the sheet (which was expected, given how transpose works). I can easily put the years back in manually, but am at a loss about how to bring the descriptions back down properly. Each one will need to be duplicated into as many rows as there currently are columns, and the method to do so eludes me. I can write VBA or Python but am lost on where to go with this.

Comment: If you have code to share, please [edit] your question with it. That helps us help you. You can also describe more in detail how you tried to use Power Query, and what issues you ran into.

Comment: I apologize, I don't have any code as I didn't get far past some loops to determine total rows and relevant columns (one's with values). I'll make an edit for the Power Query attempts, just a moment

Comment: Feel free to share those loops. That sounds like useful code after all :) Otherwise we're recreating from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case anyone stumbles on this, I solved the problem a little while ago and figured I would share the method I used here:

First, I took all the data and loaded it into an Access database.
then, using ADODB in VBA, I looped through all the years and queried for the first part of the data as well as one of the years, plus selected a column where the value was given as just that year.

Writing it all to the sheet, each year below the last, the output was exactly what was needed.

Hope this helps to anyone having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I use this to rewrite a column to a row, wrote some comments to help you follow.

```
Private Sub ColumnToRow()

    'This program will work by initially selecting the first cell in the column you wish to replicate
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Set targetRange = Cells(305, 3) 'Replace 3, 305 to whatever cell you want to begin writing to. the 3 is column C just convert the letter to corresponding number
    Do While Selection.Value <> ""
        targetRange.Value = Selection.Value
        Set targetRange = targetRange.Offset(0, 1) 'move over one column
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select 'move selection to next row
    Loop
End Sub
```